# swfobject interactive video not functioning properly

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am not able to get an interactive video to continue to play after one click when it is loaded using SWFObject. It loads fine up until the point where it calls for interaction from the viewer. I have followed the instructions for the swfobject but haven't been able to find anything about it interfering with interactivity. The video does work on its own outside of swfobject and it also works when it is just embedded, which I have also thrown into the JSFiddle.  Can anyone help at all?

```
<head>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.floodsmart.gov/floodsmart/flash/costofflooding/CostOfFlooding.swf", "flashflood", "500", "300", "9.0.0");</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="flashflood">
     Please Download Flash!
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my Fiddle so you can see it in (non)action: http://jsfiddle.net/fletchling/kuX6G/5/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox (Mac). The video loads with no errors.

Comment: I guess what he means is, nothing shows when you select one of the buttons in the last frame.

Comment: Yeah, it starts just fine.  I don't know enough about Flash to know what part of the code could be interfering with the function of the video though.